# Has Germany used water cannons for controlling crowds other than protests?

Tags: policy, germany

Germany has used water cannons for controlling protests ([example](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-35271558)).

Has it been used for controlling any other kind of crowds, such as football hooligans or out-of-control crowds at a celebration?

A brief scan of https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserwerfer#Deutschland and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_cannon#Germany didn't come up with anything (apart from watering parks during summertime!).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, water cannons have also been used for other purposes. What comes to mind is frequent usage during/after football games (e.g. [HSV vs St Pauli](http://www.gruene-fraktion-hamburg.de/sites/gruene-fraktion-hamburg.de/files/dokument/11620_ska_antje_moeller.pdf)).

Unfortunately, data of water cannon use is stored locally in the responsible agencies of the German Federal Police ([source](http://dip21.bundestag.de/dip21/btd/17/073/1707308.pdf), question 2, approximate translation from German):

> The written documentation on operations of water cannons in the  area
>   of ​​responsibility of the Federal Police remains in the respective
>   department of the Federal Police. Unless the documentation is relevant
>   under a criminal law (..)

Comment: Regarding that source: it's for the federal police only, who are usually not the primary force (as policing is a state issue in Germany). [For 2015](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserwerfer), there were 15 water cannons ("Wasserwerfer", literally "water thrower") in use at the federal level and 46 at the state level. I couldn't find anything regarding the reason for water cannons at the federal level - handling protests isn't in their area, but it might just not be explicitly stated and only regard certain areas.